# How to setup vertical only scrolling programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

On interface builder there is an option to limit a UIScrollView's scrolling to either vertical or horizontal.

However I couldn't find a property or a method in UIScrollView to enable such behavior.

Is it achieved through some other way or am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to setting the `contentSize` width as mentioned, you should also set the `scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO` to stop the horizontal bounce which will still be on.

The solution is from the question already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861986/how-do-i-enable-directional-lock-for-a-uiscrollview):

```
UIScrollView *scrollView;
CGRect size = scrollView.contentSize;
size.width = CGRectGetWidth(scrollView.frame);
scrollView.contentSize = size;
scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set your `contentSize` property such that its width is the same as your scrollview's width. Tada! No more horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that limits scrolling in those directions, it just determines whether the scroll indicators are shown (so the properties would be showsHorizontalScrollIndicator and showsVerticalScrollIndicator).