# Swiping Multiple UITableViews in horizontal page-enabled UIScrollview

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a system set up where I have a horizontal, page-enabled `UIScrollView` where each "page" is a `UITableView` with some data.  Everything works find and as expected, except visually I do not like the results when trying to horizontally swipe from one tableview to the next. Currently, when swiping to the next tableview page there is a good chance a user will slightly swipe in a diagonal motion which will not only start paging, but also move the table views up and down.

The result is unappealing, and I would like to figure out a way to essentially prevent vertical scrolling on the tableviews when I am paging horizontally, but I am exhausting my options on how to do this correctly. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [UIScrollView : paging horizontally, scrolling vertically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728014/prevent-diagonal-scrolling-in-uiscrollview)