# How can i disable/Stop Diagonal scrolling of a UI Table View?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have created two table in UIView controller and given scroll to both. I only want Horizontal and Verital movement in table NO DIAGONAL movement ?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

if (scrollView == _programGuideTable) {
    _channelGuideTable.contentOffset = CGPointMake(_channelGuideTable.contentOffset.x, _programGuideTable.contentOffset.y);

    return;
}
if (scrollView == _channelGuideTable) {
    _programGuideTable.contentOffset = CGPointMake(_programGuideTable.contentOffset.x, _channelGuideTable.contentOffset.y);

    return;
}
}
```

Now my question is how to disable or stop diagonal scrolling ?

Comment: I dont think it is posiible to stop diagonal scrolling because user swipe might not be perfectly horizontal or vertical.

Comment: please visit to this link [prevent dioganal scrolling ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728014/uiscrollview-paging-horizontally-scrolling-vertically