# Enlarging swipe angle in which a horizontal swipe is recognized in nested UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, scroll-paging

I am trying to build a UI in iOS in which there is an outer paging UIScrollView inside of which are multiple UITableViews, each representing a page. The problem I am encountering is that the angle at which I must swipe to trigger the outer paging UIScrollView to scroll horizontally is too narrow. Here is a screenshot showing what I mean.

[image]

Essentially a user has to swipe at a near-perfect horizontal angle in order for the UITableView to ignore the gesture and pass it along to the outer UIScrollView, thereby triggering a horizontal page movement. This behavior quickly becomes annoying.

I have done extensive research on stack, to no avail. Some people suggest setting [directionalLockEnabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728014/uiscrollview-paging-horizontally-scrolling-vertically), but that has no effect here (the inner UITableView has its direction locked, it's just too greedy with the angles it interprets as going in its direction). Others suggest modifications to the contentSize, but the contentSize of the views is, in point of fact, correct. Still others suggest using Gesture Recognizers, but those seem to have a delay before they kick in.

Can anyone suggest how to accomplish the behavior in the image above?