# Horizontal ScrollView inside Vertical ScrollView

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a `UIScrollView` that scrolls vertically. Inside of that, I have a `UIScrollView` that scrolls horizontally. I will call them `verticalScrollView` and `horizontalScrollView`.

My first problem was that `verticalScrollView` would scroll up and down, but the `horizontalScrollView` would not scroll at all. After **turning off Autolayout** and setting the content sizes in `viewDidLoad`, the `verticalScrollView` would always immediately scroll down the bottom upon appearing on screen and only be able to scroll up a little, but the `horizontalScrollView` (which is at the bottom) scrolls left and right perfectly.

I have tried almost everything that I have found online, but nothing seems to allow me to scroll vertically with the **Main** ScrollView (`verticalScrollView`) and scroll horizontally with the **child** `horizontalScrollView`.

I can post any more information that may be helpful. Thank you.

**UPDATE (8-15-13):** I put the `hortizontalScrollView` into a `UIView`, and put that `UIView` into the `verticalScrollView`. I am now able to scroll freely in the `verticalScrollView`, but can only scroll one swipe left or right in the `horizontalScrollView` before it snapping back.

In `ViewController.m`, I set the content sizes.

```
[_verticalScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1905)];
[_horizontalScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(960, 190)];
```

Comment: have you explicitly set frame for both along with content size?

Comment: are u setting content offset somewhere in `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear`? It is responsible for self scroll.

Comment: Only allow Vertical Scrolling in _verticalScrollView and horizontal scrolling in _horizontalScrollView. This link may help you:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728014/uiscrollview-paging-horizontally-scrolling-vertically

Comment: I explicitly set the frame for the verticalScrollView and it still scrolls down to the bottom immediately, and some of the objects seem to be out of place.

Comment: @anum90 I have not set the content offset anywhere

Comment: Ok. NSLog your current offset and let me know if setting it works.  `verticalscrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0);`

Comment: @anum90 I NSLogged my contentOffset before setting it via verticalscrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0); , and the NSLog returned (0.0000, 0.0000) for both the verticalScrollView and the horizontalScrollView. Setting it to (0, 0) seemed to do nothing. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Autosizing is top-left or not? May be something wrong in size inspector view in XIB.
Hope this can be helpful to you.

Comment: The "Mode" in the Interface Builder is set to Scale to Fill and not Top Left, if that is what you mean. I checked out the Size Inspector, and nothing appears to be wrong.