# how to disable diagonal scrolling but still be able to scroll horizontally and vertically

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, xcode6

Im having a problem with my scroll view. I can scroll up to down and left to right but sometimes the scroll view decides to pan diagonally. Direction Lock is turned on which does not help for some reason. I actually did finally come up with a way to fix it however, now when ever I scroll to the right or left (FYI: I have paging enabled) the current page before it transitions glitches and scrolls to the top because I had set the content height to 0 when the contentOffset.x becomes > than 1. Is there any way I can fix this or come at it from a different angle? Please help! Heres my "semi-success" if you will..

```
// MARK: Scroll view delegate methods
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.scrollView.contentSize.height = 1000
    self.scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.bounds.width * 2
    self.scrollView.bounces = false
    if self.scrollView.contentOffset.x > 1 {
        self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        self.scrollView.contentSize.width = scrollView.bounds.width * 2
        self.scrollView.contentSize.height = 0
    }
    if self.scrollView.contentOffset.y > 1 {
        self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = false
    }
    if self.scrollView.contentOffset.x >= self.scrollView.frame.width {
            self.pageController.currentPage = 1
    }
    else {
        self.pageController.currentPage = 0
        self.scrollView.contentSize.height = 1000
        self.scrollView.scrollsToTop = false
    }
}
```

Comment: Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728014/uiscrollview-paging-horizontally-scrolling-vertically

Comment: I came across this article before, no dice :(

Comment: Have you got solution? I am facing the same issue and spent almost 3 days please help me. Here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43731916/ios-avoid-dragging-diagonally-in-uiscrollview